# ReplaceAll() não remove "|"

Tags: java, regex

Tenho uma seguinte string "|" e gostaria de substituir por um simples "", meu código java de maneira simplificada está assim:

```
String teste = "|A|B|C";
teste.replaceAll("|","");
```

Saída:

```
"|A|B|C"
```

Gostaria que a saída fosse sem o "|", já testei com outros caracteres funcionaram normal, porém com esse não consigo fazer o replaceAll. Alguém poderia me mostrar outra forma de retirar ou a explicação do porque isso acontece?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Precisa escapar o pipe:

```
String teste = "|A|B|C";
teste.replaceAll("\\|","");
```

Veja: https://ideone.com/haskam

O pipe é um carácter especial para criar expressões regulares, e os métodos `replaceXXX` do java aceitam expressões regulares como argumento. Se você não escapá-lo, ele será interpretado como um carácter de E.R.(valor condicional de "OR") e não como um carácter comum.

As duas barras invertidas(`\\`) servem para escapar este tipo de carácter(não somente o pipe, mas também o ponto(.), por exemplo) quando você quer usá-los com seu valor nominal e não como um carácter especial.

Answer (score 3):

O primeiro parâmetro de `replaceAll` é uma expressão regular, não uma `string` constante.
Se você estudou expressões regulares direitinho, vai saber que `"|"` é uma expressão regular que bate com qualquer caractere.

Pôr um `"\\"` na frente do `"|"`, para indicar que o `"|"` é um mísero `"|"`, não uma expressão regular super-poderosa;

```
String teste = "|A|B|C";
teste.replaceAll("\\|","");
```